# How to compute $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp ~p\exp{\left[i\hslash^{-1}\left(px-t\sqrt{p^2+m^2}\right)\right]}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, quantum-field-theory

How to evaluate the integral $$I=-\frac{i}{2\pi^2x}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp ~p\exp{\Big[i\Big(px-ct\sqrt{p^2+m^2c^2}\Big)\Big/\hslash\Big]}.$$

This is the integral that appears while calculating the amplitude of propagation of a particle of mass $m$ between the points $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{x}_0$, in time $t$, in relativistic quantum mechanics and $p=|\textbf{p}|$, the momentum of the particle, and $c$ in the velocity of light in vacuum.

Comment: Your title differs slightly from your question as written. (It looks like you've set $c=1$ in the title version but not in the question itself.)

Comment: Yes. I missed c in the question. I'll fix it.

Comment: Also, if $p=|\mathbf{p}|$ then it seems as if $p$ should be positive. (On the other hand, if instead $\mathbf{p}=p \hat{x}$ i.e. $p_x=p$ then this isn't an issue.)

Comment: As far as an actual solution, you may find the [Jacobi-Anger expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi–Anger_expansion) of interest. (You will need to do some substitutions to place your integral in this form.)

Comment: Change variable to $p = mc\sinh(t)$, the integral should be some linear combination of Hankel function. Look at forumla 10.9.15 and 10.9.16 at [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9).